# Equality between two products

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

Good evening.

I'm currently working on cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_n$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$. I've proved by Möbius inversion formula that :

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{C},  \hspace{1mm} \Phi_n(x) = \prod_{d|n} (x^d-1)^{\mu(n/d)}$$

I would like to prove that if $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ is odd, then :

$$\Phi_{2n}(x) = \Phi_n(-x)$$

The proof begins with :

$$\begin{array}{lcl}\Phi_{2n}(x) & = & \prod_{d|2n} (x^d-1)^{\mu(2n/d)} \\
& = &  \prod_{d|n} (x^d-1)^{\mu(2n/d)} \prod_{d|n} (x^{2d}-1)^{\mu(2n/2d)}\end{array}$$

And I clearly don't understand why the second equality holds.

If someone could attempt to explain it to me I would be really grateful.

Comment: Try a specific example (say $n=15$), writing out both sides of the second equality in their entirety; I bet you'll understand the general equality from that one example!